# Using Regular expression to find out numbers in my text?

Tags: php, regex

I have to find out all the numbers in my document which are in the format 1., 2.,3. etc i am using the regular expression `[0-9]+.\.` this is working fine with double digit numbers but having issue with the single digit numbers like 1. 2. can someone help me out with this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the in-between unescaped dot. Because an unescaped dot in regex matches any character.

```
[0-9]+\.
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the dot after the plus. Your regex will find things like `123x.`, because `.` matches anything:

```
123 x .
^^^ ^ ^
 |  | |
 |  | +-- \.
 |  +---- .
 +------- [0-9]+
```

Remove the first dot to fix this.